# "GET PROCESSING OPTIONS" always 6D00 MasterCard

Tags: apdu, emv

This is the response when I select an application by AID (In this case: A0000000041010)

```
6F3B8407A0000000041010A530500A4D4153544552434152448701019F1101015F2D0865737074656E6672BF0C0F9F4D020B0A9F6E07018800003030009000
```

There is not PDOL in this response, so I'm trying to send the next ADPU(GPO) to a MasterCard

80 A8 00 00 02 8300 00

But I always get 6D00

I have tasted with many masterCard, but the result is the same.

I'm using [pyResman](https://www.javacardos.com/tools/pyresman) to execute these APDU

[Image of the GPO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8w4Di.png)

Thanks in advance. Regards.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution, I need to select AID before execute the GPO. (It's Mandatory, it doesn't work if you try to execute GPO directly)

1. Request AID --> 00 A4 04 00 07 A0000000031010 00
2. Request GPO --> 80 A8 00 00 04 83020000 00 (right GPO)

After that, I was able to get GPO response.

I hope it'll help